# WP: однократный обращение к БД при дублировании цикла на странице

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Wordpress 4.8.1

Задача вывести один и тот же цикл в нескольких местах на **одной** странице.
Чтобы в шаблоне было меньше кода, цикл построил в функциональном файле темы (functions.php), выглядит так:

```
function view_posts(){    
    $true_args = array(
            'post-type' => 'post',
            'cat' => '17',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        );

        $related = new WP_Query( $true_args );
        while ( $related->have_posts() ) :
            $related->the_post(); 


        echo    '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';


    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();  
}
```

В в шаблоне, соответственно, вывожу через `<?php view_posts() ?>`

Но дело в том, что каждый вызов данной функции обращается к базе данных. Смысла в этом нет, ибо выводится тот же контент.
Как можно закэшировать (или сохранить как-то) результат первого запроса и выводить на этой странице при последующих вызовах данной функции уже имеющийся результат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и так, как указано в другом ответе, но тогда придется менять вызовы view_posts() по всему проекту, а их может быть много. Проще сделать изменения в самой функции - сохранить подготовленный вывод в статической переменной и при последующих обращениях выдавать на экран уже эту переменную.

```
function view_posts() {
    static $html;

    if ( ! isset( $html ) ) {
        $html = '';
        ob_start();

        $true_args = array(
            'post-type'      => 'post',
            // 'cat'            => '17',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        );

        $related = new WP_Query( $true_args );
        while ( $related->have_posts() ) :
            $related->the_post();

            echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();

        $html = ob_get_clean();
    }
    echo $html;
}

view_posts();
view_posts();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Использовал ваш вариант, хоть он для меня и сложный. А насчёт "их может быть много" - нет, к счастью в двух местах только на главной. ) Ещё момент: запросы к БД только на той странице, где выводится функция, так ведь? Сам проверил, но решил переспросить )

Comment: Запросы к БД один раз на той странице, где вызывается view_posts(). А что сложного в ответе? Переменная типа static сохраняет значения между вызовами. ob_start() перенаправляет весь вывод echo во внутренний буфер. ob_get_clean() чистит этот буфер, возобновляет вывод на экран и помещает содержимое буфера в переменную $html.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать wp_cache_set(), но в данном случае достаточно оптимизировать саму функцию, чтобы она не выполняла лишние запросы при повторном выводе - добавляем return и выводим через echo:

```
<?php

function view_posts() {    
    $true_args = array(
        'post-type' => 'post',
        'cat' => '17',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    );

    $related = new WP_Query( $true_args );

    while ( $related->have_posts() ) :
        $related->the_post(); 

    $post .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $post;
}

$view_posts = view_posts();

echo $view_posts;
echo $view_posts;

echo get_num_queries().' запросов';

?>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Очень короткий и простой вариант реализации задачи. В этот раз отмечу ответ ниже, только из-за того, что в файле шаблона всё останется таким же компактным - просто вызов одной функции. За ваш ответ проголосую )